# How to change base URL in API Platform

Tags: api, symfony, api-platform.com, base-url, caddy

I have a route
`/books` ,
and I wanna chage it, for example, to
`/api/v1/books`
So I added to my `api_platform.yaml` the following

```
prefix: api/v1/
```

And now it works fine, my endpoint available at `/api/v1/books` , but I have some problem with frontend, because admin panel `/admin` and swagger `/docs` doesn't work, it sends me 404 error.(It's worth noting that the raw docs without swagger available on `/docs.json`) How can I resolve this problem? Only by configure caddy? Is there any way to config platform?

Comment: Submit the content of your `api_platform.yaml`

Comment: @DVN-Anakin
`api_platform:
    allow_plain_identifiers: true
#    enable_profiler: false
    mapping:
        paths: ['%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity']
    patch_formats:
        json: ['application/merge-patch+json']
        jsonapi: ['application/vnd.api+json']
    swagger:
        versions: [3]
    formats:
        jsonld: ['application/ld+json']
        json: ['application/json']
        html: ['text/html']
    defaults:
        stateless: true
        cache_headers:
            vary: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization', 'Origin']
    enable_entrypoint: true`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the API Platform's docs available [here](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/operations/#prefixing-all-routes-of-all-operations), there are 2 ways of setting-up prefixes for your routes. First, remove your `prefix: api/v1/` as it only sets-up a global prefix, which is not what you want.

**Method 1 - via php:**

Add `#[ApiResource(routePrefix: '/v1')]` in your Book entity class:

```
#[ApiResource(routePrefix: '/v1')]
class Book
{
    //...
}
```

**Method 2 - via yaml:**

Create a config file `/config/api_platform/resources.yaml` and add this:

```
App\Entity\Book:
    attributes:
        route_prefix: /v1
```